# Using libc++ standard library for ARM cross compiled to embedded application

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, llvm, libstdc++

Is it somehow possible to use LLVM´s C++ standard library `libc++` for development of ARM processor based embedded system where no OS is available? I mean to develop it on Linux, for instance, cross compile and link with `libc++` and make a single ELF file to be flashed to the target ARM based device?

Comment: As long as you can provide code for the target-specific parts, like threading and the [ABI support library](https://libcxxabi.llvm.org/), there's nothing to stop you from using it. It's a lot of work though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you please describe sligtly more in detail what is the ment role of ABI support library? Many thanks in adnvance

Comment: What do you expect from `operator new` ? Or `std::fstream` ? And what bootloader are you using on the target ? Will that even load an ELF image?

Comment: my goal is to use EABI (arm-none-eabi gcc triplet) so is that the right thing? I would say the ABI libc++ links to must match the EABI, or the compatibility layer lib++abi-eabi must be added, do I get it right?

Comment: There should be several C++ compilers that support bare metal ARM. Why re-invent the wheel? Just stick as close to the standard as possible.

Comment: @Lundin That´s for sure. I have a bare metal ARM based HW, a GCC compiler with arm-none-eabi triplet and want to use the LLVM libc++ C++ library to implement my code. So ABI comes into the game somehow. The ABI required by libc++ is libc++abi but the compiler provide EABI. So as far as I understand it those two ABIs must be compatible to use it right? Or libc++ can be configured to use EABI directly?

Comment: If you have a C++ cross-compiler for your embedded target, it will already have a C++ library suited to your target.  In fact ARM's own v6.x compiler (armclang) _is_ LLVM based and uses libc++, but the key is the library is standardised in the language standard so you should not need to port anything - that is kind of the point of a standard library!  libc++ has dependencies on the standard C library in any case - there are no target specific dependencies.  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100073_0609_00_en/index.html

Comment: What is going to do startup initialization and what is going to replace all of the syscalls?

Comment: @MartinKopecký : In that case you should use the GNU stdlib++ already included with your GCC compiler (so long as it was built to include C++ support) - why would you want to use a "foreign" C++ library.  Building teh library from source using your target compiler is the safest means of ensuring compatibility, but really... what are you doing this!?

Comment: So long story short, my whole intension makes no sense, right? Just to use what´s already existing... While using the toolchain directly from ARM (or similar), [available here](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) and just to start coding not taking care about std library as it is handled by the toolchain, right?

Comment: @MartinKopecký do you understand the connection between the C++ library and an operating system.  A fair amount of the library relies on an operating system.  Without an operating system you have to put some backend on the library to cover those holes.  Do you want those to dead end and fail do you want some baremetal thing instead, etc?  You can do this yourself certainly, at the end of the day whether or not you did it yourself what are you expecting to gain by using these without an operating system?

Comment: And the answer to that question, determines how much of a backend you need be it one you do or one supposedly done for you (as those cant possibly implement what you wanted, how could they have predicted that?  Those have to have some porting as well).